# chartjs 2+ how to specify bar chart colouring

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart, chart.js2

I'm trying to colour my bar chart using the following libraries although I'm failing to get this working and the colours are always random.  The data works fine.  I've included what versions and the order which they are loaded below.  Hope this helps.

Any help much appreciated.

Many thanks,

**Code snippet**

```
<script src="js/chartjs/Chart.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/angular-chart/angular-chart.min.js" defer></script>
```

**Library versioning**

- AngularJS v1.5.0-rc.2
- Chart.js Version: 2.3.0
- angular-chart.js Version: 1.1.1

**HTML markup**

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-bar" chart-color="backgroundColour: 'Red'" chart-data="vm.chartData.data" chart-labels="vm.chartData.legends" chart-series="vm.series" chart-options="vm.options" chart-dataset-override="vm.datasetOverride" chart-click="vm.onClick"></canvas>
```

**The final solution notes**

The final working solution sets the colours in the controller using Angular 1.5.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify colors in your controller:

```
...
$scope.vm.colors = [ '#f7464a', '#949FB1'];
...
```

and later on use in your chart:

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-bar" chart-colors="vm.colors" chart-data="vm.chartData.data" chart-labels="vm.chartData.legends" chart-series="vm.series" chart-options="vm.options" chart-dataset-override="vm.datasetOverride" chart-click="vm.onClick"></canvas>
```

Small [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WBgAmcg4iisPgXGKgF6H?p=preview)

**UPDATE:**

To set global colors you can either set `Chart.defaults.global.colors` or use `ChartJsProvider` and set colors in `.config()` as follows (see [documentation](https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)):

```
ChartJsProvider.setOptions({ colors : [ '#803690', '#00ADF9' ] });
```

Now, the last option I could not get to work, it updates some different Chart object which has no relation to the one being actually used. But the `Chart.defaults.global.colors` approach works, see updated [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WBgAmcg4iisPgXGKgF6H?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it seems to work for a bar chart but we have the ability for the user to toggle it as a pie chart.  When the pie chart is shown the colours revert to defaults?  Is there a difference in how the colours work between bar and pie charts?

Comment: I'll try setting the colours in the controller and let you know if that works.  The global setting would be nice but for now as long as the colours are rendering correctly this can be something for later.